How to get the values of a dictionary type from a parquet file using pyarrow?
I have a parquet file which I am reading with pyarrow.
In [83]: pq.read_schema('dummy_file.parquet').field('dummy_column').type
Out[83]: DictionaryType(dictionary<values=string, indices=int32, ordered=0>)

It says it is a column of dictionary type which is similar to a sql enum or pandas category type. Now I want to find the values present in the dictionary type, how do I do that?
It says in here that:

The dictionary values are found in an instance of DictionaryArray.

But how do I get this DictionaryArray?


It depends on how the parquet file is read and what is meant by "find the values". Generally, a Table's columns are ChunkedArrays, where each chunk is an Array, in this case a DictionaryArray. ChunkedArrays can be combined to get an Array.
import pyarrow as pa

column = table['dummy_column']
isinstance(column, pa.ChunkedArray)
array = column.combine_chunks()
isinstance(array, pa.DictionaryArray)

array.dictionary  # set of potential values
array.unique().dictionary_decode()  # set of actual values

The dataset api can read in batches, getting the values of each array iteratively.
pa.chunked_array(batch['dummy_column'].unique() for batch in ds.dataset(...).to_batches(columns=['dummy_column'])).unique()

Each DictionaryArray has its own dictionary. They are often the same dictionary, but not guaranteed; depends on how the dataset was written. In your case, you may be able to read just the first array's dictionary.

By values, I mean generally an enum allows only certain values say for e.g.'ON', 'OFF', 'UNKNOWN', so I wanted to know what is the set of those values? I do not mean finding out the actual values present in the column.

The code after your edit works, however, it seems I will have to load the whole file into memory for it. I wanted to avoid that, since the file is huge and it takes a lot of time. Is there any way to avoid that? That is why, I initially wanted to get the information from the schema since loading the schema does not take much time.
